# C#: XML request over TCP, connection reset by peer

Tags: c#, xml, tcp

I am sending an XML request to a machine via TCP using the following code:

```
    static void sendDataRequest()
    {
        const int byteSize = 1024 * 1024;
        byte[] messageBytes = new byte[byteSize];

        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        client.Connect("192.168.1.51", 61007);

        XmlDataDocument XMLDoc = new XmlDataDocument();
        XMLDoc.Load("send.xml");
        messageBytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(XMLDoc.OuterXml);

        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        stream.Write(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length);

        messageBytes = new byte[byteSize];
        stream.Read(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length);

        stream.Dispose();
        stream.Close();
    }
```

The log on the machine notes that the XML request arrives and executes the neccessary steps. But when it's time to send back the result, it lists the the follwoing messages:

- Transport endpoint is not connected
- Connection reset by peer

What is wrong here? Any hint will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this any language in particular?

Comment: C#, just added a tag and edited the title. Thanks

Comment: It looks like the message is being echo back and then close.  Try commenting out the Dispose() and Close() and see what happens.  What type of application are you using?  If it is a console application it may be closing.  So another test would be to put a Console.Readline() at end of method to stop applicaition from closing.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the Read is a problem. Network Stream's Read method only reads what is currently available, up to a maximum number of bytes specified. As not all of the expected bytes may be available, perhaps it is only reading some of the response, then closing the connection before the remaining data is sent from the server. The result of the Read method is the actual number of bytes read. It is important to keep track of that value. If the server closes the connection, the number of bytes read will be 0.

Here is a sample from Microsoft's documentation.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

```
int numberOfBytesRead = 0;

      // Incoming message may be larger than the buffer size.
      do{
           numberOfBytesRead = myNetworkStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);

           //Do stuff with byte data

      }
      while(myNetworkStream.DataAvailable);
```